# What Is the Correct Mimetype (in and out) for a .Py File for Google Drive?

Tags: python, rest, google-drive-api, mime-types

I have a script that uploads files to Google Drive. I want to upload python files. I can do it manually and have it keep the file as .py correctly (and it's previewable), but no matter what mimetypes I try, I can't get my program to upload it correctly. It can upload the file as a .txt or as something GDrive can't recognize, but not as a .py file. I can't find an explicit mimetype for it (I found a reference for `text/x-script.python` but it doesn't work as an out mimetype).

Does anyone know how to correctly upload a .py file to Google Drive using REST?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about using ``text/x-python`` as the mimeType? I always upload the python script using the mimeType.

Comment: That works partly, thanks! When I upload the file that way now, it looks like a python file, but when I download it, it's unknown. I notice that when I upload via REST, the extension isn't included in the name (even though it's definitely in my file path), though when I upload manually, it is, and this seems to make the difference in how it's perceived on download. (I solved this by appending an extra ".py" to the end --- [name].py.py --- so it would be converted correctly)
@Tanaike you should post your response as an answer, so I can vote it correct, since it answers my mimetype issue

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I think that `text/x-python` can be used for uploading the python scripts as the mimeType. For example, the curl sample is as follows.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [access token]" \
  -F "metadata={name: 'sampleFile.py', mimeType: 'text/x-python'};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
  -F "file=@sampleFile.py" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"
```

#### Reference:

- [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Also this is a valid Python mimetype: `text/x-script.python`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).